# pthread_create: advantages of allocate (malloc) for passing an integer as the last argument?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have found several codes using dynamic memory allocation method for passing an integer as the last argument, like this example:

```
void *foo(void *i) {
    int a = *((int *) i);
    free(i);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++1 ) {
        int *arg = malloc(sizeof(*arg));
        if ( arg == NULL ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't allocate memory for thread arg.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        *arg = i;
        pthread_create(&thread, 0, foo, arg);
    }

    /*  Wait for threads, etc  */

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, I found academic examples that use an array method, like this example passing a struct:

```
//Runnable example
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct my_Struct{
    int index;
    int value;
};
void* my_Func(void *received_struct){
    struct my_Struct *struct_ptr = (struct my_Struct*) received_struct;
    printf("index: %d  |  value: %d \n", struct_ptr->index, struct_ptr->value);
    //Now use 'struct_ptr->index', 'struct_ptr->value' as you wish
}
int main(){
    struct my_Struct mystruct_1[5];
    
    printf("\nEnter 5 numbers:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        scanf("%d", &mystruct_1[i].value);
        mystruct_1[i].index = i;
    }
    pthread_t tid[5];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, my_Func, &mystruct_1[i]);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){    
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }
}
//To run: gcc [C FILE].c -lpthread -lrt
// ./a.out

//Grepper Profile: https://www.codegrepper.com/app/profile.php?id=9192
```

What is the advantage of the dynamic memory allocation method?

Update: I found in the IBM i documentation, based on gcc, that they use [memory allocation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=ssw_ibm_i_74/apis/users_14.htm)

Comment: What differences do you know? What do you think?

Comment: Sometimes you need to allocate. Here you don't actually. It's the same as with any other dynamic allocation. If you can get away with passing a local variable address, go for it.

Comment: ... or if you can get away with passing a file-scope variable's address then go for that.  Or for integers, it is common to just cast the integer to a pointer and rely on the thread function to cast it back.

Comment: The C standard does not require that a thread be able to access another thread's automatic variables. POSIX *does* require this, but for full C portability (in case you ever want to replace POSIX `pthreads` with C11 threads) you cannot assume that accessing another thread's automatic variables will work.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I thought it might be something related to performance, or memory saving in rare scenarios, but someone said that the array method has the best performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter of `pthread_create()` is passed on the stack of the newly created thread. When it is an integer or anything else which the size is little or equal than the size of a pointer, the parameter can be passed as it is to `pthread_create()` with a cast. But it is not the recommended way to make it as it is not portable on machines where for example the integers do not have the same size as the pointers. Let's compile the following simple program:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* thread_task(void* arg)
{
  printf("Thread received parameter: %d\n", (int)arg);
  return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t tid;
  int i = 45;

  pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_task, (void *)i);

  pthread_join(tid, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

The gcc compiler raises the following warnings:

```
$ gcc pcreate.c -o pcreate -lpthread
pcreate.c: In function ‘thread_task’:
pcreate.c:6:45: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
   printf("Thread received parameter: %d\n", (int)arg);
                                             ^
pcreate.c: In function ‘main’:
pcreate.c:15:43: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_task, (void *)i);
```

Hence, using a pointer on a structure or a table entry or a dynamically allocated memory area is the way to make it portable. The preceding program could be fixed as:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* thread_task(void* arg)
{
  printf("Thread received parameter: %d\n", *((int *)arg));
  return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t tid;
  int t[1] = { 45 };

  pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_task, (void *)t);

  pthread_join(tid, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

The compiler no longer raises any warnings:

```
$ gcc pcreate.c -o pcreate -lpthread
$ ./pcreate
Thread received parameter: 45
```

Answer (score 1):

When you only want to pass one integer you can just cast it to a pointer:

```
void *foo(void *i) {
    int a = (int)i;
}

for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++1 ) {
    pthread_create(&thread, 0, foo, (void*)i);
}
```

This gives maximum efficiency and no lifetime concerns.